# How to sort two dimensional arrays by key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I've got a 2 dimensional array in this form:

```
$my_array = array(
    array("date" => "10/04/2019"),
    array("date" => "10/05/2017")
    ...
)
```

All I'm trying to do is sort it such that the array with the date `10/05/2017` comes before the other(s).

I've tried the following:

```
usort(
    $my_array,
    function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['date'], $b['date']);
    }
    );
```

It doesn't seem to work.

I still get later dates being put before earlier ones.

It's a bit more complicated than what I've demonstrated, but I think this is the core principle. If there's something wrong with the example I've given, then that itself might explain things.

**Edit** - Fixed according to correct answer and other comments. I was comparing strings and not dates. Wrapping strtotime made it so that the comparison is between dates. I also changed the format of the dates to Y/m/d (MySQL format) and it works exactly as I expect. Thanks again to all who contributed.

Comment: You're comparing strings, not dates. `4` is before `5`.

Comment: Your date strings must be in the format `year/month/day` for this alphabetic comparison to work properly

Comment: 10 is month or day?

Comment: You can change your array structure.
$my_array = array("date" =>
            array( "10/04/2019","10/05/2017")
        );

Comment: @Jonnix I considered this earlier, but for some reason did not commit to it. It makes sense.

Comment: @RahulMeshram 10 would be the day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said You have `d/m/Y` format which is not valid as per PHP documentation, you need to convert it into `d-m-Y`.
You can compare dates as below,

```
usort($my_array, function ($a, $b) {
    $aDate = strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $a['date']));
    $bDate = strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $b['date']));
    return $aDate - $bDate;
});
```

> **Note: Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking**
>   **at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a**
>   **slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the**
>   **separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format**
>   **is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and**
>   **the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.**

Source [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/075ed0bf611e2a8aa03fb287381ee5912b7ce081).

Comment: The comparison function is supposed to return a number, not a boolean.

Comment: I have made changes. Please have a look.

Comment: He says in a comment that the dates are in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. `strtotime()` will parse them as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: I have replaced `/` with `-`. You can refresh the page for reflected changes.

Comment: A combination of the information I learned from this comment and some of the below comments suggesting I am comparing strings and not date (which I've upvoted) gave me the ultimate answer. So I'm marking this one as the correct answer for the source, the quote, the demo and the concise answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

it would be better for you to compare a timestamps rather than date strings

```
$my_array = array(
    array("date" => "10/04/2019"),
    array("date" => "10/05/2017")
);

usort($my_array, function ($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) <=> strtotime($b['date']);
});

print_r($my_array);
```

demo https://3v4l.org/KGAIk

Comment: I don't have access to the spaceship operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your date format to YYYY/MM/DD, your function should start working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change your date format like this d-m-Y.
After convert your date your function will be worked fine.

See below working code

```
    $my_array = array(
    array("date" => "11-04-2019"),
    array("date" => "12-05-2017"),
    array("date" => "13-05-2018"),
    array("date" => "14-05-2016"));
usort(
    $my_array,
    function ($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
    });
print_r($my_array);
```